# Proof of closed, continuous, surjective image of a *normal* space is normal.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-explanation, separation-axioms

Let
$$p:X\rightarrow Y$$ be a closed, continuous, surjective map. I need to show that if $X$  is  normal, then  $Y$  is  also  normal.

So I used this result: **A space $X$ is normal iff for any closed set $C$  in $X$, and any nbd $U$ containing $C$, there exists a nbd $W$ of $C$ such  that $$C\subset \bar W \subset U$$**

Now, take any closed set $B$ of $Y$ and $V$ be and open set in $Y$ containing $B$. $$B\subset V\subset Y$$ Define $A=p^{-1}(B)$ and $U=p^{-1}(V)$. By continuity of $p$, $A$ is closed in $X$, $U$ is open in  $X$. Also $$B\subset V\\i.e.\ \ p^{-1}(B)\subset p^{-1}(V)\\i.e.\ \ A\subset U.$$

Since $X$ is normal, there exists an open set $W$ in $X$ such that  $$A\subset \bar W\subset U.$$ As $p$ is closed and surjective, from the  last step we can write $$p(A)\subset p(\bar W) \subset p(U).$$ Thus the statement is proved.  Is  this  correct?

Also there is  was hint given: **If $U$ is any open set containing $p^{-1}(\{y\})$ then there is an open set $W$ in $Y$ containing $y$ such that $p^{-1}(W)\subset U$**

Although I have managed to prove the statement in the hint, I could not figure out how to use that in the proof.

Somehow I know my version of the proof must be wrong.

Please help.

Comment: You have found a closed set, $p(\bar W)$, in $Y$, between $B$ and $V$. What you need to find is an open sets between $B$ and $V$ whose closure is also between $B$ and $V$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276340/image-of-a-normal-space-under-a-closed-and-continuous-map-is-normal?rq=1